# PHP Regex - Split string with comma delimiter, IGNORE comma's between tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, preg-split

Given this string:

```
$somethingawesome = '<[return date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday"));]>,<[return "cool!";]>,TRUE,foo';
```

How do I get an array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => <[return date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday"));]>

[1] => <[return "cool!";]>

[2] => TRUE

[3] => foo
)
```

Comment: Well I don't care about that...just that's what preg_match_all gives so I didn't want to focus on that.

Answer (score 4):

Based off your given string, you can use the following ...

```
$results = preg_split('/(?:<[^>]*>)?\K,/', $str);
print_r($results);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => <[return date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday"));]>
    [1] => <[return "cool!";]>
    [2] => TRUE
    [3] => foo
)
```

Or of course you could match all instead of using split ..

```
preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>|[^><,]+/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I'll be damned. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain the regex to me?

Comment: @richard it splits by `>,`, but does not capture `>`, so `>` stays with one of the elements of the array. It works only for blocks ending with `>,`

Comment: Ah I see...but that doesn't seem to be exactly right...it needs to also work for other cases. See my edit. It needs to work by splitting on commas not included inside <[]>

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain that one?

Comment: [Explanation](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%28%3F%3A%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E%29%3F%5CK%2C&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Answer (score 1):

```
 ,(?=(?:[^\]\[]*\[[^\]]*\])*[^\]\[]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `\n`.

http://regex101.com/r/aT7wM2/1

Comment: Yours is the only one that works if the last value has <[tes,t]> a value in brackets and containing a comma.

Comment: @RobertCathey thanx :)